# Where did resizeable editing boxes and syntax highlighting go?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Just now, the handle to resize editing boxes disappeared, and so did syntax highlighting in code blocks.

I would very much like getting both back.

Also: The <kbd>Review</kbd> button doesn't work. I had to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save this question.

---

Duplicate of
[JavaScript is broken @ meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381510/javascript-is-broken)

Comment: Related (MSE): [JavaScript is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381510/javascript-is-broken)

Comment: @Warcupine Ah, yes, it's all over the place I see.

Comment: Just went to post the same question. Then when I went back to the question where I had problems it seems to now be working... Let us hope it is stable.

Comment: Also brought down keybinds and reviews overall. Incredibly nasty JS error

Comment: Qt downvoted, "*just now*" will make super "a lot of sense" if this Qt gets picked up as Dupe Target, in 5 years maybe...  (I didn't read further, sorry...)

Comment: Bug reports marked as [status-completed] should not be used as duplicate targets years in the future, @chivracq. Those will be, by definition, different bugs. That's not a fault of the bug report, that'd be a fault of the future (hypothetical) close-voters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you describe was one of the many symptoms of complete brokenness of JavaScript on the Stack Exchange sites, as reported [here on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381510/javascript-is-broken). (I also noticed this shortly before going to sleep, about 7 hours ago at the time of this writing.)

As you can see there, this has been fixed. Felippe Rangel, a site developer, has implemented the fix and [written a few words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381514) about what happened and why.